# How to use TabHost in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-tabhost

I would like to make a TabHost with 3 tabs in Kotlin.

When the fragment is launch, it set a tabHost with 3 tabs, and in each tab, there is 1 fragment: Infos, news, and contact.

Here is how I set the tabs in my fragment :

```
var spec = binding.tabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_INFOS)
spec.setContent(R.id.tab_infos)
spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.infos))
binding.tabHost.addTab(spec)

spec = binding.tabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_NEWS)
spec.setContent(R.id.tab_news)
spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.news))
binding.tabHost.addTab(spec)

spec = binding.tabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_CONTACT)
spec.setContent(R.id.tab_contact)
spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.contact))
binding.tabHost.addTab(spec)
```

Now I try to set a kind of onClickListener but for tabs, like this :

```
binding.tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    fun onTabChange(tabId: String) {
        if (TAG_INFOS.equals(tabId)) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tab_infos, infosFragment, TAG_INFOS)
         }
         if (TAG_NEWS.equals(tabId)) {
             println("IF NEWS")
         }
         if (TAG_CONTACT.equals(tabId)) {
              println("IF CONTACT")
         }
     }
})
```

But this does not seems to work, I don't even know how to use the onTabChange func.

I already tried:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tab_infos, infosFragment, TAG_INFOS)
```

but it only set my fragment layout, without allowing me to modify the data inside from a `ViewModel`

How can I set a fragment in each tab? What is the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this :

```html
        binding.tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        if (it.equals(TAG_NEWS))
            setNews()
        else if (it.equals(TAG_INFOS))
            setInfos()
        else if (it.equals(TAG_CONTACT))
            setContact()
        })
```

Actually, when you click on a tab, in :

```
binding.tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
  // it: String
}
```

the value of "it" is a string, that is equal to the value of the TabSpec of the tab you clicked on. For example, here, if I click on "Contact", the value of "it" will be TAG_CONTACT.

So, in the function, you just have to put some if/else, and it will do the job ! :)